# Is the word order after "denn" correct?

Tags: word-order

In the following sentence, is the word order after "denn" correct? I thought that after the word "denn", the verb is supposed to be in the second position?

> Als Hassobjekt war er beständiger als Eurasien oder Ostasien, denn wenn Ozeanien mit einer dieser Mächte Krieg führte, hielt es mit der anderen gemeinhin Frieden.
>
> *<sub>From the [new German translation of the novel 1984](https://books.google.at/books?id=ImAGEAAAQBAJ&pg=PT16&lpg=PT16&dq=%22Als%20Hassobjekt%20war%20er%20best%C3%A4ndiger%20als%20Eurasien%20oder%20Ostasien%22&source=bl&ots=X8zMQvRiCZ&sig=ACfU3U3k2GeZqUe0tpIdt-210IZARyJnrQ&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjMz7fXqu76AhUCvaQKHVwAAaIQ6AF6BAgHEAM#v=onepage&q=%22Als%20Hassobjekt%20war%20er%20best%C3%A4ndiger%20als%20Eurasien%20oder%20Ostasien%22&f=false) (author: George Orwel, translator of this version: Jan Strümpel)</sub>*

So in the above sentence, do we understand to mean that "wenn Ozeanien mit einer dieser Mächte Krieg führte" is position 1 and then the verb "hielt" is in the second position?

Comment: Can you give a reference to the rule you consider violated? It appears, that this may be an interference with main clause/sub clause and sentence order.

Comment: @CarstenS: Please do not used comments to answer questions. Please write proper answers. If you think your answer is not worth to be posted as a proper answer, then please don't post it at all.

Comment: @CarstenS: Why do you think you deserve polite behavior in response to unwanted behavior? Don't behave unwanted! By the way, *your* comment is rude. My response to your now for good reasons deleted answer-comment was not meant to be rude. I am sorry if you took it that way. What I wrote is just a short summary of https://german.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment. Don't blame me for you ignoring the rules!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. The word "denn" is a *Hauptsatzkonjunktion*, everything after it is an independent clause that could stand alone:

> Wenn Ozeanien mit einer dieser Mächte Krieg führte, hielt es mit der anderen gemeinhin Frieden.

Within this sentence, the part "Wenn Ozeanien mit einer dieser Mächte Krieg führte" is an [*Integrierter Nebensatz in Vorfeldstellung*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adverbialsatz#Integrierte_Nebens%C3%A4tze_(Glieds%C3%A4tze)). Quoting from Wikipedia, such clauses

> können ebenso wie Adverbiale anderer Form als Satzglied des Hauptsatzes [...] vorkommen.

So the adverbial clause as a whole is in the first position of the main clause, and the finite verb "hielt" is then in the correct second position.

Answer (score 3):

The word *»denn«* connects two full sentences. The full sentence before this word describes a state or an event, and the full sentence after it describes the reason for this state or event.

> Markus kann heute nicht die Schule besuchen, **denn** er ist krank.
> Markus cannot attend school today **because** he is sick.

- First full sentence

  > Markus kann heute nicht die Schule besuchen.
  > Markus cannot attend school today.
- Second full sentence

  > Er ist krank.
  > He is sick.

Both parts can stand alone as full sentences.

Your sentence:

> Als Hassobjekt war er beständiger als Eurasien oder Ostasien, **denn** wenn Ozeanien mit einer dieser Mächte Krieg führte, hielt es mit der anderen gemeinhin Frieden.
>
> As an object of hatred, it was more enduring than Eurasia or Eastasia, **because** when Oceania was at war with one of these powers, it commonly kept peace with the other.

- First full sentence

  > Als Hassobjekt war er beständiger als Eurasien oder Ostasien.
  > As an object of hatred, it was more enduring than Eurasia or Eastasia.
- Second full sentence

  > Wenn Ozeanien mit einer dieser Mächte Krieg führte, hielt es mit der anderen gemeinhin Frieden.
  > When Oceania was at war with one of these powers, it commonly kept peace with the other.

This second full sentence has a more complex inner structure than the full sentence from the first example, but that doesn't matter. Here the second full sentence begins with a conditional clause that is an supplement of the predicate of the main clause. The whole conditional clause behaves like the word *»manchmal« = "sometimes".* (It doesn't mean the same, it just behaves like it.)

> **Wenn Ozeanien mit einer dieser Mächte Krieg führte,** hielt es mit der anderen gemeinhin Frieden.
> **When Oceania was at war with one of these powers,** it commonly kept peace with the other.
>
> **Manchmal** hielt es mit der anderen gemeinhin Frieden.
> **Sometimes** it commonly kept peace with the other.

And because this conditional clause is a subordinate clause, the verb must be at the very end. There are three types of clauses, each has strict rules for the position of the verb:

- subordinate clause with subordinate word order (verb at the very end):

  > Wenn Ozeanien mit einer dieser Mächte Krieg **führte,** ...
- main clause with word order for main clauses (verb at position 2):

  > Ozeanien **führte** mit einer dieser Mächte Krieg.
- Open question with word order for open questions (Verb at position 1):

  > **Führte** Ozeanien mit einer dieser Mächte Krieg?

Answer (score 2):

*denn* [is used to connect two main clauses](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/denn_Konjunktion) and does not count as part of either clause itself. Therefore, the *wenn*-clause takes position 1 and "hielt" is in the 2nd position as it should be.

However, even as a native speaker I had to re-read this sentence. If I were to translate the English original (which I unfortunately do not know), I would personally opt for a variant that avoids having a *wenn*-clause directly after *denn*.

Answer (score 1):

The occurrence of **wenn** after **denn** is correct here.

**"[1], denn wenn ..."**   translates to  **"[1], because when ..."**.

The word *when* starts an independent statement:

> [1], **because when** Oceania was in war with one of these powers, it maintained peace with the other.

*because* connects the first statement [1] with the second statement, which begins with *when* and represents the substantiation of the first one.